# Writing a class using another class

Tags: java

I am trying to use the Die class when writing a PairOfDice class.  Here is the Die class:

```
public static class Die {
    private final int MAX = 6;
    private int faceValue;

    public Die()
    {
        faceValue = 1;
    }

    public int roll()
    {
        faceValue = (int)(Math.random() * MAX) + 1;
        return faceValue;
    }

    public void setFaceValue(int value)
    {
        if(value > 0 && value <= MAX)
            faceValue = value;
    }

    public int getFaceValue()
    {
        return faceValue;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String result = Integer.toString(faceValue);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now what I am trying to do is to use this class to write a similar class called PairOfDice.  I want similar methods of rolling the dice, setting the face value, and so on.  However I have never done this before so I'm not sure how to approach this.  Here is what I have so far:

```
public static class PairOfDice {

    Die die1 = new Die();
    Die die2 = new Die();

    public PairOfDice()
    {
        ????
    }

    public int rollPair()
    {
        ????
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to appropriately use these objects.  Please keep in mind I am a beginner in java/programming.

Comment: You have correctly started the definition of `PairOfDice`.  Put yourself in the place of someone rolling the pair and ask yourself what methods you'd want to see and what the output would look like.  For example, `rollPair` could return the total of the two dice, but you might also want to see the individual rolls.  Where you go with this is open to many different possibilities depending on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to need anything in the constructor, you've initialized the die fields where you declared them. Just call them in your method. Something like,

```
public int rollPair()
{
    return die1.roll() + die2.roll();
}
```